# Ordering balls of different colors

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Imagine I have balls of different colors. Given all the balls (and their color) I want to know all the possible ways to order them.

Example: I have three balls, two of them are green and one is yellow. In this case I have three different orderings: `(G, G, Y)`, `(G, Y, G)` and `(Y, G, G)`.

My first question is, given the input $b_1,b_2,...,b_N$ where $b_i$ is the number of balls painted with the $i$th color, is there any mathematical expression to get the number of possible orderings?

Note that $N$ is the amount of colors and $B = \sum_{i=1}^{N}b_{i}$ is the amount of balls. Moreover, as shown in the example, balls of the same color are indistinguishable.

Finally, what would be an algorithm to enumerate all the possible orderings?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a way to find the number of possible orderings. If $S$ is the set containing all possible orderings, then 
$$n(S) = \frac{B!}{\prod_{i=1}^N b_i!} = \frac{B!}{b_1!b_2!...b_N!}$$

To find the elements of set $S$, a possible algorithm would be:

- List all the balls with their colours sequentially eg `GGGBBB`
- Pick the first element and swap it with the first element of a different colour eg `BGGGBB`. Doing this multiple times with the first element gives us the possibilities `BGGBGB` and `BGGBBG` as well
- Repeat the same logic with all the elements **but do not swap them with any character that is behind them** as these cases are already covered.

Comment: Thank you! Now that I see the formula, it makes a lot of sense. In the algorithm however, should we add a final step that repeats the whole process for every possible sequential order? (i.e `GGGBBB` first and then `BBBGGG`). Otherwise, running the algorithm with your example I only get 10 orderings, whereas the formula says I should get 20 ($6!/(3!3!)$)

Comment: Yes, I believe I missed that step out, which is why I'm getting only half the cases.

Comment: Well, after digging in more detail, I realized the algorithm doesn't work properly in all cases. If we add a final step to repeat for every possible sequential order, then some cases such as `GB` or `GBY` will yield repeated elements. And if we don't add it, then there will be missing elements in cases such as `GGGBBB`